# Azure Devops Pipelines not building referenced projects

Tags: azure-devops, tfs, tfvc

I am building a .net solution using the Azure Devops 2019 pipeline. The solution I am building is referencing projects in another directory. These projects are located in the source control however during the build I get the following error:

```
>  ##[error]C:\a\_work\9\s\UI\UIProject\UIProject.sln.metaproj(0,0):
> Error MSB3202: The project file
> "C:\a\_work\9\s\Te\..\..\BusinessLogic\MyBLLProject\MyBLLProject.csproj"
> was not found
```

If I look at the Build server drive the BusinessLogic folder is missing even though the files are located in the source control.

Shouldn´t the build server take care of referenced projects and build them as well?

Comment: Are you using Git or TFVC? If TFVC, do you have an appropriate workspace mapped in your build?

Comment: Hi @DanielMann I am using TFVC and you are right I forgot to specify the source maps for the referenced projects. Regarding the Nuget restore step, should it also restore nuget´s in the referenced projects?

Comment: Your build pipeline should include a NuGet restore step.

Comment: If you're restoring and building a .sln, the restore task should handle the restore for both projects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are trying to build/restore a simple project, the restore task will not handle the referenced project.

If you are trying to build/restore solution level .sln, the restore task will handle both projects.

However, according to your error info.

> "C:\a_work\9\s\Te....\BusinessLogic\MyBLLProject\MyBLLProject.csproj"
> was not found

It's a project not found, not some dlls not found, the issue should not related nuget side.

Just as comment suggest, you should double check your workspace  mapping relationship. Make sure the get source steps will also download the referenced projects.

Answer (score 0):

If the referenced project is in a separate repo, then your build will fail. I haven't tried it myself but you can reference other repo: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/multi-repo-checkout?view=azure-devops

Comment: The question is specifically about TFVC, not Git.